# How to get Nth Power of any number

Tags: java, puzzle

I faced an interview. where I was asked the following question

**Write a function in any of programming language that computes the nth power of a number w/o using + * or ^ or declaring a new variable inside the function or using any library function (eg Math lib in java).**

I have used pow function of java `Math.pow(a, b)`

Thanks

Comment: May I know the reason of -ve voting? is it that you donot know want to help programmers?

Comment: @Deepak Kumar Sahoo, perhaps because you posted a (homework) assignment without showing any effort of your own. Just a guess.

Comment: In FORTRAN: `I ** J` ... it doesn't use the `^` operator :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am using java programming language. The interviewer restricted you to declare a new variable inside the method better you pass it to the function. The interviewer didnt restrict you to use division operator (/) so you can use that.

```
static double getNthPowerOfNumber(double originalNumber,
        int power) {


    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (originalNumber == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        originalNumber/=1/getNthPowerOfNumber(originalNumber, --power);

        return originalNumber;
    }



}
```

if you want to get 5th power of a number 3 then write `System.out.println("4..double..." + getNthPowerOfNumber(4, 1));`

Comment: May I know the reason of -ve voting? Donot hide yourself after -ve voting. try to write the reason of -ve voting

Comment: This defines a new variable -- `int i`.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but this solution doesn't work.  `1 / originalNumber` is zero.  Integer arithmetic.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for your reply.  check my edited answer. it may work for you. and let me know if it does not work for you

Comment: I think you're gaming for points here. I mean its NOT coincidental at all that you both have the same middle and last name AT ALL.

Comment: @Jesus, search in stack overflow you will get lots of people with the same middle name and surname. I am working in a company in the mean while I am trying to help others by posting answers in stackoverflow and also i aks questions here. I am not sitting ideal. What is the benefit that that I will get to gain point. I am not employer of stack-overflow. neither i am getting revenue from this.

Comment: @I found alot of persons with your firname also with your last name. I think you donot have all those stackoverflow accounts. How all these persons have similar name like ur?

Comment: nope im the only Jesus Ramos on SO nice defence though.

Comment: also all of your friends questions are asked by him and answered by you or the other way around even if your answers are downvoted so tell me im wrong?

Comment: @JesusRamos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1176/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-sahoo-and-jesus-ramos)

Comment: yes all programmers are my friends. so i always give answers to any of questions if i can solve.

Answer (score 3):

They're asking whether you understand recursion. Considering x ^ k for some integer k,

- when k < 0, x<sup>k</sup> = x<sup>k+1</sup> / x
- when k = 0, x<sup>k</sup> = 1
- when k > 0, x<sup>k</sup> = x<sup>k-1</sup> * x

Turning this into code shouldn't be too bad. Let's use multiplication for now, and take it out later.

```
double recursivePower(double x, int k) {
    if (k < 0) {
        return power(x, ++k) / x;
    } else if (k == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return power(x, --k) * x;
    }
}
```

Now, to get rid of the multiplication. Since n * m = n / (1/m), we can rewrite the last calculation as `power(x, --k) / (1/x)`:

```
double recursivePower(double x, int k) {
    if (k < 0) {
        return recursivePower(x, ++k) / x;
    } else if (k == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return recursivePower(x, --k) / (1 / x);
    }
}
```

Fractional exponents could probably be done in the same style. If they want irrational exponents to be handled in the same way, I'd ask for Google and a fair amount of time to think about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
static public int power(int value, int pow){
    if(pow == 0) return 1;

    return value * power(value, pow -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done in JavaScript:

```
function power(num,pow){
  if (pow == 0) return 1
  num /= 1/(power(num,--pow))
  return num
}
```

Call it like:

```
power(2,0) // -> 1
power(5,2) // -> 25
power(7,3) // -> 343
```

I feel like inverse division is cheating the no * operator rule, but eh, maybe that's what they were looking for.